# How to repeat the same piece of code in JQuery with different number attached to each one?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am having issues to **target** elements which are created dynamically by PHP code. What I am trying to do is to toggle() element. It's kind of a news feed for the newest vacancies from the database.

I made it work but it is really inefficient by manually writing the piece of jquery code to target the elements like so:

```
  $('#clickMe1').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#targetCollapse1').toggle();
    if ($('#targetCollapse1').is(":visible"))
    {
      $('#change-icon1').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
    }
    else
    {
      $('#change-icon1').addClass('fa-plus').removeClass('fa-minus');
    }
  });
  $('#clickMe2').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#targetCollapse2').toggle();
    if ($('#targetCollapse2').is(":visible"))
    {
      $('#change-icon2').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
    }
    else
    {
      $('#change-icon2').addClass('fa-plus').removeClass('fa-minus');
    }
  });
```

**How to make only one piece of this code and to apply for numbers from 1-5. I tried making in a for loop but still no success??**

Here is the html/php code to see what is going on there. By the way I am using CodeIgniter and the parsing class so {vacancies} {/vacancies} is a for loop

```
<ul class="vacancies">
  {vacancies}
    <a href="#" id="clickMe{num}">
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-plus" id="change-icon{num}"></i><i class="fa fa-code"></i><span class="job-title">{job_title}</span>
      <span class="job-pubdate">{pubdate}</span>
      <div class="description" id="targetCollapse{num}">{job_descr}</div>
    </li>
    </a>
  {/vacancies}
</ul>
```

Comment: Attach some id on each element, then use `this` inside event handler to identify which element has triggered the event.

Comment: Is there a reason you use these ugly `clickMe{num}` things instead of classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
 $('[id^=clickMe]').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var number=$(this).attr('id').substr($(this).attr('id').length-1); //get the number at the end of the id
    $('#targetCollapse'+number).toggle();
    if ($('#targetCollapse'+number).is(":visible"))
    {
      $('#change-icon'+number).removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
    }
    else
    {
      $('#change-icon'+number).addClass('fa-plus').removeClass('fa-minus');
    }
  });
```

**UPDATE:**

this line `var number=$(this).attr('id').substr($(this).attr('id').length-1);` as I said gets the `id` attribute of the clicked element, then gets the last character of it (using [substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)) and stores it in a variable called `number`

Comment: It worked, but can you explain this line: var number = $(this).attr('id').substr($(this).attr('id').length-1); What exactly it is doing ? @Amin Jafari

Answer (score 0):

Abuse of HTML element id is not a good habit (but it doesn't harm).

You can use `this` inside event handler to identify which element has triggered the event. To find the element inside, jQuery provides `children` method.

So here's my soluton.

In your template:

```
<ul class="vacancies" id="vacancies">
    <li>
          <a href="#" data-id="{num}">
              <i class="fa fa-plus change-icon"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-code"></i><span class="job-title">{job_title}</span>
              <span class="job-pubdate">{pubdate}</span>
              <div class="description">{job_descr}</div>
          </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In your javascript:

```
$('#vacancies').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    // var num = $(this).attr('data-id');
    // {num} in template, but it seems useless in this case

    var $desc = $(this).children('.description'),
        $icon = $(this).children('.change-icon');

    // you can use children to locate children elements, no need to assign id
    $desc.toggle(); // toggle visibility
    if ($desc.is(':visible')) {
        $icon.removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
    } else {
        $icon.removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
    }

    /*
       or simply use toggleClass
       $icon.toggleClass('fa-minus').toggleClass('fa-plus');
    */
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: @Unsparing Sorry I dropped a pair of parenthesis mistakenly.

Comment: yeah I fixed this and I changes $('#cacanice') to $('#vacancies') cause that was wrong as well and still it doesn't work. The var num is not used anywhere in your code is it meant to be like this ? Why you event need the data-id if you are not using it ? Maybe that's why it doesn't work ? @ChiChou

Comment: @Unsparing Finally I realize that these elements are not siblings. They are inside <a> so I have to use `children`. Does it work now?

Comment: still doesn't work. : ( It really looks like the most efficient code if it works

Comment: I tested it on jsfiddle, but without your actual backend enviroment I can't figure out what's wrong. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$('[id^='clickMe').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault()
var i = this.id.replace('clickMe','');
$('#targetCollapse' + i).toggle();
if ($('#targetCollapse' + i).is(":visible"))
{
  $('#change-icon' + i).removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
}
else
{
  $('#change-icon' + i).addClass('fa-plus').removeClass('fa-minus');
}
```

});